# Validate datestring "dd.MM.yyyy" to see if input is numeric

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I have a textbox containing a date in the format "dd.MM.yyyy". Now I want to use a RegularExpressionValidator to see if the format matches "digit digit . digit digit . digit digit digit digit" (without spaces)

How does the regular expression look like for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the regex `"\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}"` should work - but it won't validate that the values are sensible. For example, it will allow "55.66.3000".